# How to duplex print with HP8715 in Ubuntu

Tags: scanner

I want to scan with Ubuntu, full duplex.
My printer is HP8715 .
simple-scan only scans one page, even if I select both pages :D
What should I do?

Is  there a program that work better?
thank you :D

[hp8715 simple scan doesnt work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxmmT.png)

Comment: "Duplex" refers to *printing* both sides of one sheet. The HP8715 does not seem capable of *scanning* both sides of one sheet. Perhaps you mean *scanning multiple sheets* using the Automatic Document Feeder?

Comment: duplex has to  be configured inside the printer .  Of course with the automatic document feeder.

Answer (score 0):

As I thought it doesn't work I wanted to use just a USB for scan.
Then I needed to check the printer settings.. I changed them to duplex printing.

Then I instantly tried it again at my with simple-scan.

And it worked :D